# Is it right to say "I do A, do B, and do C"?

Tags: parallelism

I want to state I did 3 things with different verbs. Is the following right?

> We use it, load it and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. It is a simple sentence with one subject and three verbs. No problems there.

Comment: thank you meepyer.